# Multi Column List Box

Tags: vba, ms-access, listbox

*Please Refer to the Image First

Basically i want a code when you select an item from the product name combo box and when you type the quantity it should appear in the the list box
with two columns when you press next..

I tried all the similar other codes including .additem but they don't work.

The Naming of the items are as follows;

Product Name Combo box = " cmbProductName "

Quantity Purchased Text Box = " txtQTYPurchase "

List Box = " lstMaterialSummary "

[image: Refer the Image First]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the properties window of the `lstMaterialSummary` ListBox, set the property `ColumnCount = 2`.

then add this handler for the `Next` Button (change to the appropriate name)

```
Private Sub ButtonNext_Click()
    lstMaterialSummary.AddItem cmbProductName.Value & ";" & txtQTYPurchase.Value
End Sub
```

Comment: I did all the things as you said.. but it still gives an error saying "Compile Error : Method or Data Member not found" 

 The Coding I did was 


`Private Sub cmdNext_Click()

 With lstMaterialSummary
        .AddItem cmbProductName.Value
        .List(.ListCount - 1, 1) = txtQTYPurchase.Value
    End With

End Sub`

Comment: @GayuruGunawardana does the edited code work for you?

Comment: it works perfectly.. thank you very much :) you deserve a treat